# Connecting Authors with Published Papers

Tags: scraping

I'm specifically interested in tying doctors to their published papers. The key issue is that using name alone will result many collisions. I'm wondering what set of features I would need to reliably connect a doctor with a given published paper? Aside from weak features such as specialty, is there any database that has a link between doctor NPI and papers published?

[I've seen this on linking NPIs to authors in PubMed](http://hhs.ddod.us/wiki/Use_Case_24:_Mapping_of_NPI_number_to_PubMed_ID#Solution) but it seems rather unreliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an easy question to answer even for groups with a lot of leverage such as [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/home) (RG). RG has it's own (I assume proprietary) `author matching algorithm` [which has caused problems in the past](http://www.scilogs.com/in_scientio_veritas/researchgate-heal-thyself-please/).

They use the name of the author (in different combinations) to suggest [authorship to RG users](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/Authorship) (so has you said, it does causes a lot of problems). Every once in a while users that are not the author accept the suggestions and, from the portal point of view, gain the equivalent reputation. It's a serious business that requires quite a bit of R&D before making a decision.

That being said I can't answer with certainties only with reasonable possibilities. A few questions I would make (and hope to answer with a bit of data analysis):

- What is the probability that an author with a confirmed publication in an identified journal will publish in that journal again? - **Journal Name**
- What is the probability that an author that has partnered with other authors will repeat the same co-authoring combination? **Co-author Names**
- What is the expected time story for publishing for each author? Authors rarely publish articles 20 years apart. Typically they publish more and more, or less and less. **Time frame**
- How frequently do authors change the institution they belong to? **Institution Name**
- What are the preferred keywords for a given author? **Key Names**
- What are the preferred citations made by a given author? **Bibliography**

All of the questions above require quite a bit of [Text Mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining) and [String Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_matching_algorithms), as well as solid dataset to start your mining.

Some publishers have their own [API](http://api.elsevier.com/documentation/SCIDIRSearchAPI.wadl) although I can't say much about permissiveness (never tried it myself). [RG has been promising one for years](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_Researchgate_API) but, as far as I know, it still does not [exist](https://github.com/researchgate).

An unlikely thing I remember now is the inspiring story of [Aaron Swartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz). This activist, along with other persons, successfully managed to create large open archives for books and articles. Should that information still exist it might be worth your time to take a look [there](https://openlibrary.org/).

Also if you have a list of the journals you are considering (you've mentioned only "doctors" which is a bit vague) you can try and see with the publisher if they have any way of accessing their database.